# Error when saving data on SQL-Server 2005 as both hard- and softcopy

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am developing a project using VS 2008 and SQL-Server 2005.
I have used `varchar(150)`-field for saving a normal string, which have to save

1. softcopy
2. hardcopy
3. both (softcopy & hardcopy)

It works when saving as softcopy or hardcopy but for both (softcopy & hardcopy) it throws the following error:

> string or binary data would be truncate. The statement has been terminated.

When I restart the application after this error had occurred everything works perferctly.

I tried to use `Nvarchar(Max)` for the same field but the error was all the same.

Please give me suggestion to avoid this error.

Comment: check your data length in your query or stored procedure where you are assigning value to the filed saved in db (Ref: as you change it to `nvarchar(max)` but its not working).

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are updating the column with larger size than what it can accomodate. Check for blank space in the column value

Answer (score 0):

*This exception occures when your datatype,size does not match with database field attributes.*

It may be because your column length is less than your inserting data.

so if you increase your column length to that which can occupy the data you input then issue will get resolved.

If you use `Nvarchar` (Unicode character data) data type then you need to insert the data with `N'` as a Prefix like this:

```
Set @var = N'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `string or binary data would be truncate. The statement has been terminated` comes when the size is exceeded. Try to update your size from `varchar(150) to varchar(500)`.

Or check your data length in your query or stored procedure where you are assigning value to the filed saved in db (Ref: as you change it to `nvarchar(max)` but its not working).

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you are trying to insert too much data into a field that has a limited size, in your case 150.